# Find all functions $f$ over reals such that $f(xy) \geq f(x+y)$ for all $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$.

Tags: functional-equations

> Find all functions $f$ over reals such that $f(xy) \geq f(x+y)$ for all $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$.

We have that $f(x) \geq f(x+1)$ and $f(0) \geq f(1)$. I am wondering how to use these conditions to solve the problem. It seems like using a telescoping sum might be useful with the $f(x) \geq f(x+1)$ condition.

Comment: It's easy to see $f(0)\ge f(x)$ for all $x$. Also $f(0)\le f(-x^2)$...

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich What does that show?

Comment: Was just supposed to show how you might get started.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have $f(0) \geq f(y)$ for all $y$, setting $x=0$.

Now $f(0) \geq f(-x^2) \geq f(x-x) = f(0)$, so equality holds throughout and $f$ must be constant on $x \leq 0$.

And if $x>0$, $$f(0) \geq f(x) = f((-\sqrt{x})^2) \geq f(-2 \sqrt{x}) = f(0)$$
so equality holds throughout and $f$ is constant on $\mathbb{R}$.

It is easy to see that any constant will do, so the answer is that "$f(x) = r$ for all $x$" is a solution for each $r \in \mathbb{R}$, and it is the only possible set of solutions.

Comment: How does $f(x) \geq f(y)$ and $f(-x^2) \geq f(x)$ mean $f$ is constant on $x \leq 0$?

Comment: @user19405892 Added the words "so equality holds throughout".